# Generating random numbers in matlab biased towards the boundaries

Tags: matlab, probability

I want to generate biased random numbers in matlab. Let me explain a bit more, by what I mean by biased.
Lets say I have a defined upper bound and lower bound of 30 and 10 respectively.
I want to generate N random numbers biased towards the bounds, such that the probability of the numbers lying close to 10 and 30 (the extremes) is more as compared to them lying some where in the middle.
How can I do this?
Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You could use a little trick with a Gaussian distribution (**randn** in Matlab) and a bijection from R to [lowerbound,upperbound]. 

Do you know exaclty what distribution you are trying to get? (i.e. do you know the distribution function of your variable?), Or are you just trying to get "something approximatively biased toward the bounds"?

Comment: @BillBokeey Hi..thanks for your reply. I don't specifically know the distribution function but just want it to be more biased towards the bounds. How do I proceed in such a case?

Comment: I'm posting an answer

Comment: @BillBokeey Thanks a ton :) As per the plot, this should work for me, but if you could explain the code a bit..it would be great. I'm not that well acquainted with matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% Upper bound
UB = 30
% Lower bound
LB = 0;
% Range
L = UB-LB;
% Std dev - you may want to relate it to L - maybe use sigma=sqrt(L)
sigma = L/6;
% Number of samples to generate
n = 1000000;
X = sigma*randn(1,n);
% Remove items that are above bounds - not sure if it's what you want.. if not comment the two following lines
X(X<-L) = [];
X(X>L) = [];

% Take values above zero for lower bounds, other values for upper bound
ii = X > 0;
X(ii) = LB + X(ii);
X(~ii) = UB + X(~ii);

% plot histogram
hist(X, 100);
```

[image]

I used a normal distribution here but obviously you can adapt to use others.. you can change the sigma also.

Comment: What if LB<0, UB>0 and |LB|>|UB| ?

Comment: works fine with LB < 0 and UB > 0.... of course I assume lower bound (LB) is smaller than upper bound (UB) what's the issue there?

Comment: The LB and UB values are constant defined values. LB being 540 and UB being 600

Comment: @gregswiss Yes..it does :) But I would like to understand the later part of it begining from where "ii" has been defined

Comment: Sakshi: it randn generates values that are around zero. The idea I used is to take the negative values and shift them to the upper bound, and take the negative values and shift them to the lower bound. ii is used to index the values of X that are above zero. X(ii) then represents the values of X that are above zero and X(~ii) the values of X below zero.

Comment: @BillBokeey can you explain why the downvote please? the solution is simple and works as required.

Comment: @gregswiss Yes..I thought so. But if you could explain, why are we taking  values above zero. Is it because our LB is defined to be zero? In my actual application LB and UB are defined to be 540 and 600 respectively.

Comment: X = random numbers centred at zero, by definition of randn. Apply a scale factor 'sigma' to X. Takes values above zero and add LB to them ( see line X(ii) = LB + X(ii)). Then take values below zero and add UB to them  (see line X(~ii) = UB + X(~ii))

Comment: Ok great! understood :) Thanks :)

Comment: @gregswiss : problem i had with your solution is that you might end up with a bunch of values being equal to the boundaries values, contradicting the fact that the probability to get a certain number from samples of a continuous random variable should tend to 0 when the size of the sample tends to infinity. OP didn't forbid it, though, so i changed to an upvote

Comment: @gregwiss : and if you remove items that are out of bounds you don't control the size of the output sample anymore

Comment: thanks unlikely to have value at the boundaries because X was not clamped but values out of bound are removed. I agree with your point on sample size tho and that could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

To generate random numbers for an arbitrary distribution, you have to define the inverted [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function). Let's say you called it `myICDF`. Once you got this function, you can generate random samples using `myICDF(rand(n,m))`.