# plotting data between concentric circles of known radii

Tags: matlab, random, geometry

I have a vector of 1000 random numbers biased towards the bounds of 540 and 600. I need to plot this data as a wriggly circular path between two concentric circles of radii 540 and 600 respectively. How do I do this?
Presently, I'm able to plot the concentric circles of given radii, but if I try to plot the given random data which is between the bounds 540 and 600, it is plotted along the width between the two concentric circles. I want it to be plotted as a noisy circular curve between the concentric circles.
I hope I'm able to explain my point
If anyone can tell me, how do I do that. Thanks

Here is the link to my previous post, wherein I had to generate random numbers biased towards the two well defined bounds
[Generating random numbers in matlab biased towards the boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942905/generating-random-numbers-in-matlab-biased-towards-the-boundaries)
Now I need to plot the same data, as explained above.

This is the image I get:

[image]

Comment: I want to do the above task in matlab. Thanks

Comment: I can show you the current plot, but how do I post an image here?

Comment: @Sakshi : Edit your question, you'll be able to add an image by clicking the Image button in the post toolbar

Comment: Put the code to generate that plot with sample data, the plot you getand a good explanation of the plot you expect, with visual example if possible. If you can not post an image, put it somewhere in the internet and post a link, we will add it

Comment: You can also link to your older question about how to get your set of random numbers biased towards the bounds --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942905/generating-random-numbers-in-matlab-biased-towards-the-boundaries

Comment: @AnderBiguri Here is the link to the image: http://i.imgur.com/EI8C6O0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want is a circular plot, so the first idea that comes to my mind is to use polar coordinate.

First we get your sample of around 1000 random datas biased to the bounds of your [540 600] interval following [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942905/generating-random-numbers-in-matlab-biased-towards-the-boundaries/32945142?noredirect=1#comment53716014_32945142).

Note that this algorithm will not always get you exactly 1000 values as the out of bound values are removed.

So we'll do something like this :

```
%Get the size of the sample

P=length(X);

% Generate P Angles uniformly distributed between 0 and 2*pi*(P-1)/P
% Note generating an angle equal to 0 and an angle equal to 2*pi would
% mean that we have 2 points with the same angle, and that s something
% you generally want to avoid 

Angles=(0:P-1)*(2*pi/P);

% Plot your points with the markers (polar coordinates) in '-+', 
% - means that you want a line to be drawn between the points and
% + means that you want a + marker on every point

plot(X.*cos(Angles),X.*sin(Angles),'-+');

%tell matlab to wait so you can add the circles

hold on

% add circle of 540 radius

plot(540*cos(Angles),540*sin(Angles),'-r');

%add circle of 600 radius

plot(600*cos(Angles),600*sin(Angles),'-r');
```

For the final result of :

[image]

**Update  : About getting the angles randomly distibuted**

We'll have to define our Angles diffrently. We still need a vector of length P, but randomly distributed. This can be achieved by taking P random numbers between 0 and 1, and then multiply this vector by 2*pi in order to get randomly distributed values between 0 and 2*pi.
Last step is to order this vector in order to keep the ordering of your data.

```
Temp=rand(1,P)*2*pi;
Angles=sort(Temp);
```

For a final result of :

[image]

Another lead woult be to take a sample of 1000 gaussian random numbers and use them modulo 2*pi :

```
Angles=sort(mod(randn(1,P)*2*pi,2*pi));
```

Comment: yes..something like this plot where most of my data points are biased towards the two bounds

Comment: Actually they are on this plot, except the lines between the points make them look like they're not (i took the datas created in your precedent post) :

Comment: Yes I need to plot the same data from my previous post just as above between concentric circles of radii 540 and 600. Could you please explain, how did you do this?

Comment: Yes I will, but first : Do you want the lines between the points or just the points themselves?

Comment: Would prefer the lines too.

Comment: @BillBookey Please explain :)

Comment: @BillBookey Thanks a ton :)
But could you explain how the angles are being generated? A bit confused in that. I was doing something like this                                                                                                           t = 0:pi/499.5:2*pi;
% R_in=540;
% R_out=600;
% plot(sin(t)*R_in, cos(t)*R_in); hold on
% plot(sin(t)*R_out, cos(t)*R_out);     and how do you get those lines joining the points?

Comment: I just genrate uniformly distributed points bewteen 0 and 2*pi*(P-1)/P in order to not have 2 points with the same Angle. The rest is pretty understandable step by step - step1 : generate a vector 0:(P-1) - step2 : multiply it by 2*pi/P in order to go from 0 to 2*pi*(P-1)/P with increments of 2*pi/P

Comment: Would be exactly the same as Angles=0:(2*pi/P):(2*pi*(P-1)/P)

Comment: the lines joining the points are obtained in the plot call : plot(X.*cos(Angles),X.*sin(Angles),'-+');   '-+' means that you want a line between the points and a + marker on each point

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot! :)  God bless!

Comment: Edit: How do I vary Angles non-uniformly? Something like Angles=(0.95)*kt+rand(1,1)*0.1k would work? I want the angles to vary randomly, speeding up and slowing down at times

Comment: Do yu still want your values to be ordered along the circle or not?

Comment: yes..along the circle but unlike the previous way where a definite step size was defined leading to uniformly distributed points. was trying to use the equation in my last comment

Comment: The important part of my question was the word ORDERED

Comment: Sorry..I'm still not clear with the implication of "ordered" :(
Will try to see if your suggestion helps though